# Is there a tutorial in ANNO 2070?

Tags: anno-2070

Well I just got the game, and so far, I'm completely stumped.

I click on the campaign quickstart button on the menu, and I was promptly thrown into the game with little to no explanation what-so-ever on how to play!

Is there some sort of tutorial I'm missing here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Start the Single Player Campaign. It will serve as the Tutorial in the first missions.

Comment: I did, but it didn't really tell me HOW to do anything. It just told me to do it.

Comment: I have to agree with the OP on that the tutorial-campaign isn't much of a tutorial at all. As a long-time Anno player, I have struggled with the new features such as power generation and ecobalance. I would heed Tauriqs advice and watch videos and lets-plays.

Answer (score 3):

Try this video. It's an hour long and looks incredibly informative.